# Uninitialized Automatic variable forcing value to random value

Tags: c++, variables

This may look like a trivial problem. Sorry in that case, I am not able to find the actual way. I understand that automatic variable are un-initilaized. So a code snippet provided below is likely to dump in block-2

```
char *p;  
if(NULL == p)  
{  
   //do something  block-1 statement
}  
else  
{  
  //do something else  block-2 statement
}
```

Now, in most of the platform the default value of the automatic variable is either 0 or NULL especially SUSE Linux flavours.

### Question

a. Is there any compiler flag or any other option which will force the setting up of local variable to a "junk" value if un-initialized?

PS : I know that static analyzer tool will be easily able to detect the problem. I just wanted to know if this can be done at run time also through some flags/option setting.

I am using SUSE 10/HP-UX and AIX platforms.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.  Block 1 or 2 will be hit/harddrive erased on any platform.

Comment: @DanDan: Undefined according to the standard, yes, but that doesn't mean the program's behavior will neccessarilly be eratic. This is the sort of situation where "zomg nasal demons" is simply not a concern.

Comment: Disagree. You have a quite real possibility of weird behavior. Assume a system where the stack grows on demand. In particular, the stack growth is triggered by a guard page after the top of stack. The guard is normally triggered by the first write to that page.  In this particular case, though, if `p` is the first variable on the guard page, `p` and thus the guard page is read before it is written. What happens? Up to the OS, but "block 1 or block 2 will be hit" no longer is an exhaustive list.

Comment: @MSalters: But that is still well defined behavior. You can point to it and say "on your system, due to unpredictable stack growth, you can not rely on anything." This guy is asking for a compiler flag to provide well defined results for strictly undefined behavior, so simply calling the behavior undefined is inappropriate.

Comment: yes I agree with @Dennis, I just want a defined predictable crash every time I run into this trouble. And Yes,Yes,Yes I know static analysis tool will help me and should/must be the first point of problem detection always. My only reason for this question is - If standard dictates that automatic variable have erratic value (when un-initialized), then there must be a way to force it. If "most" of the time it give 0/NULL then I feel "something" missing. :)

Comment: The standard dictates nothing like that. It doesn't even dictate that such variables _have_ a value, and my previous comment explained how that could happen (no memory allocated to hold a value before first write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is an artifact of how memory is usually allotted to processes on Unix.

Since the stack segment is not stored in the disk-file image of the executable the OS has to allocate new pages to the stack at program start. These come as **zero-filled** initially, same as the `.bss`. This initial zero-filling of the stack is historical. There was an attempt to "simplify" it to not do that. Too many programs broke, so the move was abandoned.

Run your program for a while, make multiple function calls, - you'll see "junk" on the stack eventually :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need static analysis tools - just compile with the -Wall flag to get the comiler to warn you about the problem. and don't look for "band-aid" solutions - simply initialise the variable yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First, why do you want to do this at runtime when you can most likely catch it quicker and easier with compiler warnings or static analyzers?

I'm not aware of a compiler flag to do what you want, but I'm pretty sure external tools such as valgrind and Purify can monitor for such things.